# Homebrew, Class or race?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

I want to make a class/race for people with spirit animals. I want this to be a born trait, but I want it to improve over time. Most of my ideas point to Class, (but mine are called "soul changers" and its supposed to be a born trait that causes the character to be a spellcaster) which would make more sense? A class that you need a born trait? or a race that is forced to be a certain class?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out the [tour] to see how we work here. This question's been closed as opinion-based, mostly correctly -- it's arbitrary which you pick. Since there isn't a best or correct answer here, this is more a matter for forums, and you can discuss how to build this class on [any of this list we'd recommend here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). Note that there are classes that have "you were born like this" features.

Comment: Which classes have that? if I read about them, maybe I could figure out on my own how I should handle this.

Comment: See the opening description of the [Sorceror](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sorcerer#content); typically the whole "you were born naturally gifted with magic" class of the series.

Comment: Comments really aren't for continuing the discussion. As Doppelgreener said, It's best for you to engage in a discussion on a forum to help figure this out or hop into the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) after you get some more rep.

Comment: @MeteorstarTheArcher, if you make a chat for this, please post here where it is; I would be interested in discussing this.  I've been working on some similar ideas.

Comment: @PhilBoncer I would love to, but I only have 16 reputation and I need 100 for creating a chat and 20 for commenting on one. on the other hand, if you can make one for me, once I get 20 reputation we can talk about it. I would love to hear your ideas and bounce off ideas off each other. hey, maybe we could make an actual thing for soul animals with our combined creativity?

Comment: +1 to get you into chat--[chat] would be a decent place to start. (If you start a separate room it'll likely get little traffic, but you can almost always find people willing to help brainstorm in "main" chat.)

Comment: You've got the rep now, come on in!